# Difference between geodesics on surfaces and paths under gravitiational fields

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, kinematics, differential-geometry

Sorry for the maybe silly question, but I'm a math student and I'm not able to find the answer to this question from the physics point of view.

Let us suppose that a ball is set in a non equilibrium state in a mountain, with $0$ initial velocity. Let us treat the ball as a point and let $M=\{(x,y,z)|f(x,y)=z\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the profile of the mountain.
Physically I think that the trajectory followed by the ball will be as follows: let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),f(x(t),y(t))$ be the trajectory curve such that at $t=0$ the point $\gamma(0)$ is where we set the ball. Since the gravity is pointing down in the $z$ direction we have that $\gamma(t)$ satisfies the following differential equation $$\gamma^{"}(t)=\Pi_{\large{T_{\gamma(t)}M}}(-g(0,0,1))$$ where $\Pi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow T_{\gamma(t)}M$ is the linear projection and $g$ is the classical gravitational constant.
But clearly there is another "canonical" trajectory attached to $M$ and to the point $\gamma(0)$, i.e. the unique geodesic $\Gamma \subset M$ starting at $\gamma(0)$.
Clearly by definition the geodesic $\Gamma$ is parametrized by arclength, while the physical trajectory $\gamma(t)$ certainly not.

However is it true that in general $\gamma(t)$ and $\Gamma$ have the same support as subsets of $M$? In the negative case is possible to find a surface $S$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that that geodesics of $S$ are physical trajectory of non equilibrium points of $M$?

Comment: Usually we refer to a "particle" rather than a ball. I don't quite follow the notation in the equation you set apart from the text. What is the $f$ that shows up in $\gamma (t)$? But keep in mind that the acceleration is provided by both gravity and contact forces with the mountain. And that, for general shapes of mountain, the contact forces may be different depending on the magnitude of the speed of the particle.

Comment: @BillOnne thanks for the comment, the $f$ (the same $f$ as in the definition of $M$) is involved when you compute the tangent space providing the linear projection map $\Gamma$. Yes, I was tacitly supposing that are no contact forces.

Comment: The "no contact force" case is pretty easy. Heh heh.